# Find the missing rows by comparing before and after when merging dataframes

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I want to find the rows that disappeared by comparing before and after when merging dataframes.

previous dataframe:

(Each row is unique)

```
  index date  code col2
      0 10/01 1111    B
      1 11/02 2222    A
      2 12/11 5555    B
      3 12/15 1111    B
```

current dataframe:

(Each row is unique, too)

```
  index date   code col2
      0 10/01 1111    B 
      1 12/11 5555    B 
      2 12/17 2222    D 
      3 12/19 4444    B
```

The result of the merger :

```
  index date  code col2 delete
      0 10/01 1111    B 
      1 11/02 2222    A   yes
      2 12/11 5555    B 
      3 12/15 1111    B   yes
      4 12/17 2222    D 
      5 12/19 4444    B
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You simply need to do an `outer` join and set `indicator` to `TRUE`. Then you need to filter the required rows by your indicator column.

```
import pandas as pd
df_prev = pd.DataFrame({'code':[111,222,555,666],
                   'col':['A','B','B','C']})
df_after = pd.DataFrame({'code':[111,222,555,777,888],
                   'col':['A','B','B','D','E']})

df_merged = pd.merge(df_prev, 
                     df_after,
                     how = 'outer',
                     left_on = ['code','col'],
                     right_on = ['code','col'], 
                     indicator = True)

deleted_rows = df_merged.loc[df_merged._merge == "left_only",]
```

Then results will be

```
 >> deleted_rows
    code    col     _merge
3   666     C   left_only
```

Answer (score 2):

There are no rows missing here. You are performing a merge statement without passing any parameter to (how=). so by default it is doing inner join.

#### If you want every single row even with the duplicates you should do an outer join.

consider following code in your case.

```
data_frame1.merge(data_frame2, how='outer')
```

Comment: The columns of "data_frame1" and "data_frame2" are same. I want to find a column that is in "data_frame1" but not in "data_frame2".